# Finding a perpendicular vector from a line to a point

Tags: geometry, vectors, matlab

Let's say I have an arbitrary linear line described by $y=mx+b$. I also have a point $P(x_1,y_1)$ that is not on that line. I suppose $P$ can be anywhere relative to the line. How can I find the vector $v$ the stretches from the point to the line (and is perpendicular to it)?

Here's what I tried: I figured that the difference in the $x$ and $y$ components ($\delta y$ and $\delta x$) basically describe a vector twice as large as $v$ but in the same direction. So I tried finding $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ by the following:

$\delta y=y_1-(m\cdot x_1 +b)$

$\delta x = x_1-(y_1/m - b/m)$

The vector V is then $[\delta x/2, \delta y/2]$. I divide by two because I figure the vector described by $[\delta x, \delta y]$ goes all the way to the top left corner of the imaginary rectangle that is completed by $\delta x$ and $\delta y$.

Am I correct? If not, why? Regardless if I am, is there an alternative or smarter way to accomplish this? I would appreciate any input here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I will write the line $l$, defined by $y=mx+b$, as a parametric vector equation,

$$
l = \left\{\vec{u}_0 + \lambda \vec{u}_1, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}, \tag{1}
$$

where $\vec{u}_0$ and $\vec{u}_1$ are equal to,

$$
\vec{u}_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{pmatrix}, \tag{2}
$$

$$
\vec{u}_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{pmatrix}. \tag{3}
$$

This notation will be useful when projecting an arbitrary point $P$ onto the line. Any point on $l$ can be seen as a scaled version of $\vec{u}_1$ with its origin at $\vec{u}_0$. The point $P$ can be seen as a vector with its origin at $\vec{0}$. Both origins have to be the same in order to be able to project $P$ onto the line. This can be done by adding $\vec{u}_0$ to its origin and subtracting $\vec{u}_0$ from $P$, which is visualized in the following figure:

[image]

The [projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Projection.html) of $P$ into $l$, denoted with $P'$ with its origin at $\vec{0}$, can be found with,

$$
P' = \frac{(P - \vec{u}_0) \cdot \vec{u}_1}{\vec{u}_1 \cdot \vec{u}_1} \vec{u}_1 + \vec{u}_0. \tag{4}
$$

When writing $P$ as $(x_p,y_p)$ and using equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $\vec{u}_0$ and $\vec{u}_1$, then $P'$ can be simplified to,

$$
P' = \frac{(x_p + m (y_p - b)}{1 + m^2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{pmatrix}. \tag{5}
$$

The vector $\vec{v}$, with its origin at $P'$ and point to $P$, can be found with,

$$
\vec{v} = P - P'. \tag{6}
$$

Comment: I just want to tell you how much I love this answer. Really appreciate the figure too. I think I'll be using this idea in the future.

Comment: @JohnAlperto Thanks, I tried to explain it as visually as possible, such that one might understand better some of the underlying principles involved and be able to apply them to other similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_2, y_2)$ be the foot of perpendicular drawn from the given point  $P(x_1, y_1)$ to the line: $y=mx+b$ then the line joining $(x_1, y_1)$ & $(x_2, y_2)$ is perpendicular to the given line hence we have the following condition 
$$\text{slope of line joining}\ (x_1, y_1) \ \text{&}\ \ (x_2, y_2)=\frac{-1}{\text{slope of line:}\ y=mx+b}$$
$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{-1}{m}\tag 1$$

Since, the foot of perpendicular $(x_2, y_2)$ is lying on the line: $y=mx+b$ hence, by satisfying the equation we have $$y_2=mx_2+b\tag 2$$ Now, solving (1) & (2), we can find out the coordinates $(x_2, y_2)$ as follows $$x_2=\frac{x_1+m(y_1-b)}{1+m^2},\ \  y_2=\frac{mx_1+m^2y_1+b}{1+m^2}$$

Hence, the vector $v$ from $P(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$ perpendicular to the line is determined as follows  $$\overrightarrow v=i(x_2-x_1)+j(y_2-y_1)$$

Comment: Just to be clear, is your answer essentially the same as mine except that you don't divide by 2?

Comment: Yes, this method is straight forward.

Comment: OK, one more question, can you explain how equation 1 works again?

Comment: The product of slopes/gradients  of the perpendicular lines is $-1$

Comment: OK great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let the line $L$ be
$$ax+by+c = 0 \tag{1}$$
Let P be
$$ P = (x_1, y_1) \tag{2}$$
Now, to make calculations easier, shift the coordinate system by the vector given by the position $P$, so that $P$ is the origin of the new coordinate system and the new equation for $L$ is
$$ a(x+x_1) + b(y+y_1) + c = 0 \tag{3}$$

If we let a the constant $s$ be the constant at the end of this equation, $$s = ax_1 + by_1+ c$$ The equation for $(3)$ becomes much shorter,
$$ax + by + s = 0 \tag{4}$$

To calculate the vector that we need, which is from the line to $P$, we need to write the equation for the perpendicular line to the line $L$ and through the point $P$, which in the new coordinate system is given by $$ bx - ay = 0 \tag{5}$$
After a few manipulations we get $ bx = ay $ and $$x = \frac{a}{b} y$$ Now the intersection of $L$ and its perpendicular yields the other point of the vector. Substituting this into $(4)$ yields
$a\frac{a}{b}y + by + s = 0$ then $(a^2 +b^2)y = -bs$, and finally
$$y = \frac{-bs}{a^2 + b^2}$$
And similarly $x$ can be shown to be
$$x = \frac{-as}{a^2 + b^2}$$

But since the vector begins at $(x,y)$ and goes to $P$, it's $$\begin{pmatrix} -x \\ -y \end{pmatrix}$$ So the vector may be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b \end{pmatrix} \times \frac{ax_1 + by_1 + c}{a^2+b^2}$$
If the line is given as $y = mx +b$, we need only to rewrite it as $mx + b - y = 0$ and the new value is
$$\begin{pmatrix} m\\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \times \frac{mx_1 + b -y_1}{m^2+1^2}$$.